# Writing function calls to a function within a unity game does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono.cecil

I am attempting to write a mod engine for a game.

To achieve this, i decided i would add a reference to my engine dll in Unity's Assembly-CSharp game code file, then using Mono.cecil i wrote a call to the engine into one of the functions the game calls when it loads.

However, this (The function call) does not work, the code executes like normal but my engine is not called. I also tried doing it with dnSpy, which also did not work. I was able to add code in there that would write to file if the function was called, which worked, so either something has gone wrong with the way the engine is called (Or referenced) or unity does something to stop that behavior.

Adding a reference using mono.cecil:

```
private void AddRef(string path)
    {
        var _Module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Assembly-CSharp.dll"));
        var nameReference = new AssemblyNameReference("ModEngine", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0));
        _Module.AssemblyReferences.Add(nameReference);
    }
```

Adding the call to a function (Probably not a very efficient way to do it):

```
private void ReWrite()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Assembly-CSharp.dll"); //Get path to asm
        var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(path); //Load asm
        //Get types that match criteria
        var toInspect = assembly.MainModule.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => t.Methods.Select(m => new { t, m })).Where(x => x.m.HasBody);
        toInspect = toInspect.Where(x => x.t.Name.EndsWith("GlobalStats") && x.m.Name == "LoadStatData");
        foreach (var method in toInspect) //Get the type
        {
            var processor = method.m.Body.GetILProcessor(); //Get IL processor
            var call = processor.Create(OpCodes.Call, method.m.Module.Import(typeof(WeNeedToModDeeperEngine.ModEngine).GetMethod("Main"))); //Create a call opcode to the engine
            var lastInstruction = method.m.Body.Instructions[method.m.Body.Instructions.Count - 1]; //Get the last command

            processor.InsertBefore(lastInstruction, call); //Write the call before the first command

        }
        assembly.Write("Assembly-CSharp-patched.dll"); //Write the assembly
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to get this (Getting the mod engine to be called) working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you cant mess with the Assembly-CSharp file because of unity, instead i am using UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll and injecting into Display or Input